# ¿Puedo usar alguna libreria en scripts de python para trabajar con bitlocker?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encriptación

Estoy empezando en programación con Python 3.6 y estoy buscando la manera de hacer un script con el que pueda activar, desactivar, bloquear y desbloquear *bitlocker* a través de un programa con Python, pero no sé qué debo utilizar para trabajar con *bitlocker*.

No encuentro qué debo importar, o si debo trabajar con comandos en dos o powershell desde Python ni cómo hacer esto.

Comment: Para empezar podes investigar sobre la librería [`libbde`](https://github.com/libyal/libbde) que permite acceder a volumenes encriptados con BitLocker.

Comment: Gracias Matías Olivera, echaré un vistazo a la librería que me indicas.

Comment: Creo que voy teniendo un poco mas claro lo que quiero, en este caso, lo que haré será crear una función para cada botón, activar, desactivar, etc, 
En esa función, me gustaría poder usar comandos de DOS o de PowerShell, pero para poder usar estos comandos:
Qué librería debo usar?
No sé como encontrarla.

Comment: Para lo que quieres usa el módulo [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), en concreto `subprocess.popen` o `subprocess.run` dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer y del grado de control que quieras sobre el proceso.  También [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) (`os.popen`) te puede servir. Ambos pertenecen a la biblioteca estándar. La pregunta es demasiado amplia ahora mismo, posiblemente termine cerrada. Infórmate un poco más y cuando te decidas, si tienes problemas sobre código concreto puedes preguntar por algo más específico. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta FjSevilla, has sabido responderme justo con lo que necesitaba, para mi era una pregunta concreta, lo siento si se entiende de otra manera, estoy empezando y lo que a alguien le puede parecer muy amplio a otros nos parece muy concreto.
En cualquier caso gracias de nuevo!

Comment: rgmagritte la pregunta original es amplia porque hay muchas formas de enfocarla y de hacer lo que quieres (diferentes métodos y librerias usar), tu comentario la hace menos amplia cuando dices que te gustaría usar comandos del sistema directamente. En SO se buscan preguntas que tengan una respuesta correcta, por esos se evitan las preguntas sobre recomendaciones. Si por ejemplo decides usar subprocess y tienes un problema con tu código, esa pregunta agregando el código si es muy concreta y perfectamente válida. Mirate [help/on-topic] y [help/dont-ask] para más información. Saludos.

Comment: Entiendo que no puedo entonces solicitar recomendaciones a una curtida comunidad de programadores? Me disgusta oír esto, pues los que empezamos no tenemos los suficientes conocimientos para saber que camino coger, en un campo tan amplio como el de la programación, donde como tu comentas, hay diferentes formas de afrontar un mismo problema. Para mi, tu respuesta fue clarificante y me ayudó ya que no sabía ni por donde empezar a buscar. De todas formas no voy a entrar a un debate sobre normas de uso de esta comunidad, solo digo que me disgusta no poder solicitar recomendaciones de quien mas sabe

Comment: Por favor, que alguien reformule mi pregunta de la forma correcta para que no se cierre, gracias.